# No wayland-egl support when building Qt from source on Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, wayland

I have a Raspberry Pi 5 and installed the current Ubuntu 22.04 on it. Now I want to compile Qt on my own on that machine.

Unfortunately, when I do the configuration, it says that no `wayland-egl` support is detected.

Nevertheless, I compiled Qt, but no program will start because the plugins for Wayland is of course missing. What can I do so that Wayland is supported?

What can I also do to run successfully Qt-based app on the Pi?

My configuration:

```
-prefix /opt/Qt/Qt5.14.1 -opensource -confirm-licensee -nomake examples -dbus -no-separate-debug-info -release
```

I also installed `libxcb-xinerama0-dev` and `libxcb-xkb-dev`.

Comment: Presumably you need to have the wayland-egl dev package(s) installed (headers etc.)?  Or have I missed the point?

Comment: I did that already: installed libwayland-dev package, but no solution to that problem!